# Play audio file from the assets directory

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, assets, android-assets

I have the following code:

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("AudioFile.mp3");
player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
player.prepare();
player.start();
```

The problem is that, when I run this code, it starts playing all the audio files in the assets directory, in alphabetical order instead of just playing the audio file I requested. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to play audio files from the assets directory?

Follow-up question: 
Is there a difference between keeping audio files in the assets directory and keeping them in the res/raw directory? Besides the fact that they don't get ids if they are in the assets directory. If I move the audio files to the res/raw folder then I have a problem with reusing `MediaPlayer`s because there is no id parameter for `setDataSource()`. I can't find a good guideline for handling this kind of problem.

Answer (score 252, accepted):

```
player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
```

> Your version would work if you had only one file in the assets
>   directory. The asset directory contents are not actually 'real files'
>   on disk. All of them are put together one after another. So, if you do
>   not specify where to start and how many bytes to read, the player will
>   read up to the end (that is, will keep playing all the files in assets
>   directory)

Comment: It worked. Thanks. But I think my version SHOULD have also worked.

Comment: Your version would work if you had only one file in the assets directory.
The asset directory contents are not actually 'real files' on disk. All of them are put together one after another. So, if you do not specify where to start and how many bytes to read, the player will read up to the end (that is, will keep playing all the files in assets directory)

Comment: This is the code path that I am using but it doesn't work:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124378/mp3-audio-in-the-android-assets-folder-fails-to-play-from-a-signed-and-zip-align

Comment: +1 for answering a completely unrelated question I had about asset files!

Comment: @SarwarErfan mind blown by the implementation of assets directory >_<

Comment: @SarwarErfan, when I try to use this method, I get a "java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed", is there any way I might be able to get around that problem?

Comment: I have total 10 files in assets folder and i want to read each file as per request.Like i want to play first audio from assets,what to do for that?

Answer (score 81):

This function will work properly :)

```
// MediaPlayer m; /*assume, somewhere in the global scope...*/

public void playBeep() {
    try {
        if (m.isPlaying()) {
            m.stop();
            m.release();
            m = new MediaPlayer();
        }

        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("beepbeep.mp3");
        m.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
        descriptor.close();

        m.prepare();
        m.setVolume(1f, 1f);
        m.setLooping(true);
        m.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is m? you are initializing m = new MediaPlayer(); after and used it before?

Comment: Hi @Umar, I have take Global variable MediaPlayer m = null; then I have assigned in playBeep() function

Comment: Keep in mind `MediaPlayer m` must be `static` or have another **reference**. If you have `m` in a function without any reference, `GC` will "collect" it

Comment: sometimes audio does not play to the end

Comment: looping to true is that forever playing?

Answer (score 8):

Here my static version:

```
public static void playAssetSound(Context context, String soundFileName) {
    try {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = context.getAssets().openFd(soundFileName);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
        descriptor.close();

        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(1f, 1f);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

[image]

start sound

```
startSound("mp3/ba.mp3");
```

method

```
private void startSound(String filename) {
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
    try {
        afd = getResources().getAssets().openFd(filename);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        assert afd != null;
        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        player.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    player.start();
}
```

Comment: This is useful when the file is in a subfolder of assets directory. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Fix of above function for play and pause

```
  public void playBeep ( String word )
{
    try
    {
        if ( ( m == null ) )
        {

            m = new MediaPlayer ();
        }
        else if( m != null&&lastPlayed.equalsIgnoreCase (word)){
            m.stop();
            m.release ();
            m=null;
            lastPlayed="";
            return;
        }else if(m != null){
            m.release ();
            m = new MediaPlayer ();
        }
        lastPlayed=word;

        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = context.getAssets ().openFd ( "rings/" + word + ".mp3" );
        long                start      = descriptor.getStartOffset ();
        long                end        = descriptor.getLength ();

        // get title
        // songTitle=songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");
        // set the data source
        try
        {
            m.setDataSource ( descriptor.getFileDescriptor (), start, end );
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            Log.e ( "MUSIC SERVICE", "Error setting data source", e );
        }

        m.prepare ();
        m.setVolume ( 1f, 1f );
        // m.setLooping(true);
        m.start ();
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

this works for me:

```cs
public static class eSound_Def
{
  private static Android.Media.MediaPlayer mpBeep;

  public static void InitSounds( Android.Content.Res.AssetManager Assets )
  {
    mpBeep = new Android.Media.MediaPlayer();

    InitSound_Beep( Assets );
  }

  private static void InitSound_Beep( Android.Content.Res.AssetManager Assets )
  {
    Android.Content.Res.AssetFileDescriptor AFD;

    AFD = Assets.OpenFd( "Sounds/beep-06.mp3" );
    mpBeep.SetDataSource( AFD.FileDescriptor, AFD.StartOffset, AFD.Length );
    AFD.Close();

    mpBeep.Prepare();
    mpBeep.SetVolume( 1f, 1f );
    mpBeep.Looping = false;
  }

  public static void PlaySound_Beep()
  {
    if (mpBeep.IsPlaying == true) 
    {
      mpBeep.Stop();
      mpBeep.Reset();
      InitSound_Beep(); 
    }
    mpBeep.Start();
  }
}
```

In main activity, on create:

```cs
protected override void OnCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
  base.OnCreate( savedInstanceState );
  SetContentView( Resource.Layout.lmain_activity );
  ...
  eSound_Def.InitSounds( Assets );
  ...
}
```

how to use in code (on button click):

```
private void bButton_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
  eSound_Def.PlaySound_Beep();
}
```

Comment: WWWWWWhat is eUNIS?

Comment: eUNIS is custom static class with variable Assets, that is reference to application assets.