# Problem with Audio/Video

Tags: android

In my code i am using VideoView and MediaController for playing my audio/video files. The problem is that I need to place my audio/video files in assets folder but i am not able to play the audio/video files when placed in assets folder and give path as "file:///android_asset/audio.mp3". I get this error "Command PLAYER_SET_DATA_SOURCE completed with an error or info PVMFErrNotSupported". But the same code runs when i place my audio/video files in sdcard and give its path(/sdcard/audio.mp3). Does this mean that i cannot play audio/video files when placed in assets folder? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your audio/video file for playback is large (several MB or more) you should consider placing it on SD card anyway.

Comment: Hey thanks for the advice, but i need it to be in the assets folder :(. Also the sample which i am using for testing purpose is small in size so i don't think that size is the problem right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path is wrong.
For playing audiofiles from the assets directory, you have to follow the advice in the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289038/play-audio-file-from-the-assets-directory).