# load a MediaPlayer from a Uri in a context assets

Tags: android, media-player

I have an audio file in my assets directory. assets/audio/dance.mp3.

If I run context.getAssets().list("audio");  it shows up.

But when I try to use MediaPlayer.create(context,uri)  it always fails and returns null.

none of this seems to work

```
private void tryLoad(String path,Context context)
{
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
    this.audioPlayer =  MediaPlayer.create(context,uri);
    if (this.audioPlayer == null)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "loadAudio: audioPlayer is null. current assets"+ uri.toString()) ;
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "loadAudio: WORKED"+ uri.toString()) ;
    }

}
public void loadAudio(Context context)
{
    if (this.audioPlayer != null)
        return;
    if (this.audioFile != null && this.audioFile.length() >0)
    {
        try 
        {
            tryLoad("/dance.mp3",context);
            tryLoad("dance.mp3",context);
            tryLoad("audio/dance.mp3",context);
            tryLoad("/audio/dance.mp3",context);
            tryLoad("assets/audio/dance.mp3",context);
            tryLoad("/assets/audio/dance.mp3",context);
            tryLoad("\\dance.mp3",context);
            tryLoad("dance.mp3",context);
            tryLoad("audio\\dance.mp3",context);
            tryLoad("\\audio\\dance.mp3",context);
            tryLoad("assets\\audio\\dance.mp3",context);
            tryLoad("\\assets\\audio\\dance.mp3",context);
        }   
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "loadAudio exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do it because the `MediaPlayer` expects an URI and it's impossible to create an URI for an assets file. Try creating a `MediaPlayer` object and setting a data source to it using the `MediaPlayer.setDataSource(FileDescriptor)` method. You can get the `FileDescriptor` object using the `AssetManager.openFd()` method and then calling the `AssetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor()` method for the returned object.

I haven't tried this solution, so it's just an idea. But I hope it'll work.

Comment: oops.. didn't see your answer (just edited an old one) anyway - +1 for being faster :)

Comment: @madmik3 Hi, you can award a bounty to this answer if you think it's right. Otherwise your bounty may be just lost because it's not awarded automatically when you accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have asked something like this question, look at this post [MediaPlayer issue between raw folder and sdcard on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018153/media-player-problem-between-raw-folder-and-sdcard-on-android/6019208#6019208). I hope this help you

Answer (score 1):

you cannot call mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor()); on an asset file as it will play all the assets. Instead follow the solution in this thread:
[Play audio file from the assets directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289038/play-audio-file-from-the-assets-directory)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the file in the `res/raw` folder and then loading it with:

`MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);`

From: [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html%20Android%20documentation)

Comment: that requires that they files are hard coded and thats what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: sorry, this wasn't clear from your original question. Have you tried this instead: `mp = new MediaPlayer(); AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("dance.mp3"); mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());`