# MediaPlayer issue between raw folder and sdcard on android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am making an app for playing songs with a seek bar. If I play from the raw folder it works but if I play a song from the sdcard it shows a null pointer exception.

```
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.t1); // it works

//  switch to sdcard
mediaPlayer.setDataSource("/sdcard/t1.mp3"); // null pointer exception.
```

I do not know what is the problem. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure the path you give to `setDataSource()`
is exactly correct. The best way to do this, instead of hardcoding the reference to '/sdcard/', is to use `android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Try this, I think it will help you

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
File path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path + "/t1.mp3");
```

I hope this help you