# how to play audio file in android

Tags: android, audio, android-widget, media-player

I have a mp3 file in my android mobile, lets it's a xyz.mp3 somewhere in my sdcard.
How to play it through my application?

Comment: You may also put `xyz.mp3` into `res/raw/` and then reference it via `R.raw.xyz`. However, then you have two choices: `MediaPlayer` and `SoundPool`. For efficient memory management, you should use a library to work with those classes: https://github.com/delight-im/Android-Audio

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Simply you can use `MediaPlayer` and play the audio file. Check out [this nice example](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-play-video-and-audio-android) for playing Audio:

```
 public void audioPlayer(String path, String fileName){
    //set up MediaPlayer    
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        mp.setDataSource(path + File.separator + fileName);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: for GUI You have to go for yourself and take help of images and all through layout.

Comment: "what about the GUI" LOL

Comment: how to get path and file name??

Comment: You should never use "/". You should always use `File.separator` instead.

Comment: does audio gets mute if incoming call comes?

Comment: The kind of things I enjoy. It worked for the first test, and as I used to have a full path which included a name I did my code this way public void audioPlayer(String path){
        //set up MediaPlayer
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            mp.setDataSource(path );
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Answer (score 18):

If the audio is in the local raw resource:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
mediaPlayer.start(); // no need to call prepare(); create() does that for you
```

To play from a URI available locally in the system:

```
Uri myUri = ....; // initialize Uri here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Answer (score 12):

@Niranjan, If you are using a raw file from res/raw folder, ie., reading a file stored inside the project, we can use:

```
mediaplayer.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse("android.resource://urpackagename/res/raw/urmp3name");
```

If you have to use from SD card:

```
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
 File path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path + "urmp3filename");
```

See this related question: [MediaPlayer issue between raw folder and sdcard on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018153/media-player-problem-between-raw-folder-and-sdcard-on-android)

Comment: If you let me know why -1, I will learn whats wrong with the above answer?

Comment: Probably the -1 is because you posted an answer to the original question (i.e. how to play an audio file); if you wanted to reply to Niranjan's comment, you should have added a comment yourself, under Lalit's answer

Comment: Hmmm......They should have told me that in the comment, I would have changed it......anyway, thanks for letting me know........

Comment: I'd rather see: 
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() +"/res/raw/urmp3name"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Answer (score 4):

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button play;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        play=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        play.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.song);// the song is a filename which i have pasted inside a folder **raw** created under the **res** folder.//
        mp.start();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mp.release();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The replay from https://stackoverflow.com/users/726863/lalit-poptani is great one, it worked the first time, but as I used to have the full path of the file, I did it this way

```
public void audioPlayer(String path){
        //set up MediaPlayer
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            mp.setDataSource(path );
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Credit to http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-play-video-and-audio-android