# How to start a mediaplayer by pressing a button in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I am new to android and I am now doing an exercise which the application has already stored a audio file(mp4) in /res/raw/ folder and this file can be referenced in android Service class as `R.raw.audiofile`. In the Service class I have created three methods

```
onCreate();
onStartCommand();
onDestroy();
```

in `onCreate()` I have created a `MediaPlayer` and in `onStartCommand()` I have started the `MediaPlayer`

```
mp.start() and 
returned STRT_STICKY
```

to play it and in `onDestroy()` I have done this:

```
mp.stop();
```

in the xml layout I have created a Button with this attribute:

```
android:onClick="onClickStart"
```

which calls a method in the MainActivity and this action now shoud playback the audio. however, I am now stuck here on how to link this to the music file so that this button should start the audio. can anyone please give me some idea?

so I have one Main activity class and one (My)Service class (extends to Servcie) and one xml file for layout to perform this action.

Comment: Try to take a look at this [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291731/how-to-play-audio-file-in-android

Comment: yeah, but it is a different story as it is invoking a audio file out site of the application. now this is a file that is stored in the application itself and the questions is more towards how to implement the button in the main activity to invoke the service and the button is called in xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can communicate between the Activity and Service using an Intent or by binding to the Service and sending a Message. In this case, binding to the Service and sending a Message in the Button's click listener is probably the cleanest approach. That also gives you the opportunity to appropriately update UI by passing a Messenger/Handler in the replyTo field of the Message. I'll edit with code snippets when I get to a PC.

Edit:

Most of the code you need is in the Android docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

The basic idea is that you need to create a `Handler` class inside your `Service`. The proper way to do this (to avoid leaking the `Handler` and the accompanying Lint warning) is as follows:

```
private static class MyHandler extends Handler {
    private WeakReference<MyService> mService;

    public MyHandler(MyService service) {
        mService = service;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // Your message handling here...
        // You can use the members/methods of the Service with
        //   mService.get().____
    }
}
```

Then you would create a `Messenger` member and override the `onBind` method in the `Service`, like so:

```
private Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(new MyHandler(this));

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mMessenger.getBinder();
}
```

Then you need to call `bindService` with an appropriate `Intent` and `ServiceConnection` from your `Activity`. See the link for a code example. In the `onServiceConnected` method of the `ServiceConnection` you can stash a `Messenger` for the `Service` with:

```
@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
    mMessenger = new Messenger(service);
}
```

You can likewise create a `Handler` and `Messenger` in the `Activity` and supply it as the `replyTo` field of any `Message` objects sent to the `Service`. In that way, you can tell the `Activity` whether the `MediaPlayer` started successfully or not and update UI as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You need a OnclickListener for your Button like

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Perform action on click
             }
```

Look here for the [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)