# How to play audio in the background when a url is been loaded to the webview?

Tags: android, url, audio, webview

I would like to play a audio file from assets file from the background when a url is been loaded to webview in front.Any example or snippets would be helpful.Thanks.

Comment: What is your problem ? How to play a sound ? Or how to know when the content is fully loaded in the webview ? Need some details.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url-in-android) to know when the page is fully loaded into the WebView.

Then add the [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289038/play-audio-file-from-the-assets-directory) to play the audio.