# Android - assistance with audio player

Tags: android, media-player

i am new to android development. In my app ive implemented an audio player, it plays soounds from teh sd card. i want it to play and show the list of only those audio files that i provide in a folder the app workspace (like the images we give in drawable)
here is the code. Thank you in advance

Play.java

```
public class Play extends ListActivity {
private static final int UPDATE_FREQUENCY = 500;
private static final int STEP_VALUE = 4000;

private MediaCursorAdapter mediaAdapter = null;
private TextView selelctedFile = null;
private SeekBar seekbar = null;
private MediaPlayer player = null;
private ImageButton playButton = null;
private ImageButton prevButton = null;
private ImageButton nextButton = null;

private boolean isStarted = true;
private String currentFile = "";
private boolean isMoveingSeekBar = false;

private final Handler handler = new Handler();

private final Runnable updatePositionRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                updatePosition();
        }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.play);

selelctedFile = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.selectedfile);
seekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
playButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.play);
prevButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.prev);
nextButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.next);

player = new MediaPlayer();

player.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletion);
player.setOnErrorListener(onError);
seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChanged);

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

if(null != cursor)
{
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        mediaAdapter = new MediaCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list, cursor);

        setListAdapter(mediaAdapter);

        playButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
        prevButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
}
}

@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(list, view, position, id);

        currentFile = (String) view.getTag();

        startPlay(currentFile);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);
        player.stop();
        player.reset();
        player.release();

        player = null;
}

private void startPlay(String file) {
        Log.i("Selected: ", file);

        selelctedFile.setText(file);
        seekbar.setProgress(0);

        player.stop();
        player.reset();

        try {
                player.setDataSource(file);
                player.prepare();
                player.start();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

        seekbar.setMax(player.getDuration());
        playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);

        updatePosition();

        isStarted = true;
}

private void stopPlay() {
        player.stop();
        player.reset();
        playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
        handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);
        seekbar.setProgress(0);

        isStarted = false;
}

private void updatePosition(){
        handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);

        seekbar.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition());

        handler.postDelayed(updatePositionRunnable, UPDATE_FREQUENCY);
}

private class MediaCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

        public MediaCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c) {
                super(context, layout, c, 
                                new String[] { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION},
                                new int[] { R.id.displayname, R.id.title, R.id.duration });
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
                TextView title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.displayname);
                TextView duration = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.duration);

                name.setText(cursor.getString(
                                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)));

                title.setText(cursor.getString(
                                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE)));

                long durationInMs = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(
                                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION)));

                double durationInMin = ((double)durationInMs/1000.0)/60.0;

                durationInMin = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(durationInMin)).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP).doubleValue(); 

                duration.setText("" + durationInMin);

                view.setTag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)));
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);

                bindView(v, context, cursor);

                return v;
        }
}

private View.OnClickListener onButtonClick = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                switch(v.getId())
                {
                        case R.id.play:
                        {
                                if(player.isPlaying())
                                {
                                        handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);
                                        player.pause();
                                        playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                        if(isStarted)
                                        {
                                                player.start();
                                                playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);

                                                updatePosition();
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                                startPlay(currentFile);
                                        }
                                }

                                break;
                        }
                        case R.id.next:
                        {
                                int seekto = player.getCurrentPosition() + STEP_VALUE;

                                if(seekto > player.getDuration())
                                        seekto = player.getDuration();

                                player.pause();
                                player.seekTo(seekto);
                                player.start();

                                break;
                        }
                        case R.id.prev:
                        {
                                int seekto = player.getCurrentPosition() - STEP_VALUE;

                                if(seekto < 0)
                                        seekto = 0;

                                player.pause();
                                player.seekTo(seekto);
                                player.start();

                                break;
                        }
                }
        }
};

private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener onCompletion = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                stopPlay();
        }
};

private MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener onError = new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                // returning false will call the OnCompletionListener
                return false;
        }
};

private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChanged = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                isMoveingSeekBar = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                isMoveingSeekBar = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
                if(isMoveingSeekBar)
                {
                        player.seekTo(progress);

                        Log.i("OnSeekBarChangeListener","onProgressChanged");
                }
        }
};
}
```

play.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_light"
    android:padding="10dip">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/selectedfile"
            android:text="Not file selected"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="middle"/>

    <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/seekbar"
            android:max="100"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>

    <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_light">

            <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/prev"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous"/>

            <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/play"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"/>

            <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/next"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_next"/>

    </LinearLayout> 
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: or you could just guide me to a audio player tutorial which plays predefined sounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your music to assets directory (ie. create subfolder titled 'sounds') and then list the contents of it by method:

```
myContext.getAssets().list(”sounds");
```

Then you have to attach the asset to MediaPlayer object:

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(myContext.getAssets().openFd(soundPathInAssets));
```

You should also see this thread (because the bit of code I presented to you would play whole directory): [Play audio file from the assets directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289038/play-audio-file-from-the-assets-directory)

EDIT: Code from example project (in case of deleting file on my dropbox):

**MainActivity.java**

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        Button playPause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        playPause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mControl.isPlaying()){
                    mControl.pause();
                } else {
                    mControl.start();
                }
            }
        });
        try {
            list.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getAssets().list("music")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                String path = (String) list.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                try {
                    AssetFileDescriptor fd = getAssets().openFd("music/"+path);
                    mMediaPlayer.reset();
                    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(fd.getFileDescriptor(), fd.getStartOffset(), fd.getLength());
                    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private String[] content;

        public MyAdapter(String[] content){
            this.content=content;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return content.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return content[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView==null){
                convertView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                TextView cv = (TextView) convertView;
                cv.setTextSize(18);
                cv.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            }
            TextView v = (TextView) convertView;
            v.setText(content[position]);
            return v;
        }
    }
    MediaPlayerControl mControl = new MediaPlayerControl() {

        public void start() {
            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }

        public void pause() {
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
        }

        public int getDuration() {
            return mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
        }

        public int getCurrentPosition() {
            return mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        }

        public void seekTo(int i) {
            mMediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
        }

        public boolean isPlaying() {
            return mMediaPlayer.isPlaying(); 
        }

        public int getBufferPercentage() {
            return 0;
        }

        public boolean canPause() {
            return true;
        }

        public boolean canSeekBackward() {
            return true;
        }

        public boolean canSeekForward() {
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_transparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="PlayPause" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: do i create the folder in my worlspace?

Comment: I've made an example for you: https://www.dropbox.com/s/heiez87p57i83f3/test-project.zip