# Android : How to play a sound depending on the button that is pressed?

Tags: java, android, audio, playback

I'm new to Android and I would like to play a sound depending on the button that was pressed by the user.

I managed to play a sound on button press but I had to specify the file that I wanted to be played.

What I want to do is to find a way to dynamically set the R.raw.arthaswhat5 parameter so that it is set up to the last button pressed.

```
public void listen(View w){
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.arthaswhat5);
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

I thought that naming the buttons the same way as my files could help but I don't really understand how this R thing works... I know I can get the v.getId() int to know which button is pressed but I can't use this id to play a sound accordingly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`R.raw` like `R.id` in basic words like pointer to where these values have been stored.

When you save some image or wav file under raw folder, after Project refresh you can call it like `R.raw.arthaswhat5` that returns `int`.

By the same way `R.id` is generated when you add new GUI element.

There is no dependency between `R.raw` and `R.id`. `R.raw` points to raw folder when `R.id` points to your view XML.

```
from `View` you can fetch id to you it for `if` statement or `switch`
```

like

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.your_button){ /*...*/}
```

**[Edit]**

if you have > 100 songs I would use `assets` folder instead `raw`. Because in `raw` all names must be lower-case and you can't create there sub-directories. Will be hard to handle and maintain.

Comment: Ok I see. But what I have to do is to make playable a huge library of sounds (more than 100).

According to what you say, I will have to create an ArrayList or something like that containing <buttonId, soundId>, however I will generate the interface on-the-go to make folder selection available for the user.

Do you know if there would be a way to get the id of a previously generated GUI element?

Comment: if you have 100 songs I would use `assets` folder instead `raw`. Because in `raw` all names must be lower case and you can't create there sub-directory. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289038/play-audio-file-from-the-assets-directory. And yes, just create `List` of song names

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a Sound Pool
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

In your "res" folder add a folder called "raw" and put your sound files in there.
I used .m4a files and it worked for me, but I'm not sure which other formats are supported.

Here's a snippet from a code I used in my app,
to play a sound use the following code:

```
int flip = 1,scratch = 2,wrong = 3,correct = 4,pop = 5;
SoundPool soundPool;
HashMap<Integer, Integer> soundPoolMap;

setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

soundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
soundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
soundPoolMap.put(flip, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.flip, 1));
soundPoolMap.put(scratch, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.scratch, 1));
soundPoolMap.put(wrong, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.wrong, 1));
soundPoolMap.put(correct, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.correct, 1));
soundPoolMap.put(pop, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.pop, 1));

soundPool.play(soundPoolMap.get(flip), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
```

Edit: Almost completely neglected a part of your question.
You need to use a switch/case scope to determine which button is clicked and apply the correct sound to it accordingly:

```
public void listen(View v) {
   switch(v.getId()) {
      case (R.id.button1):
         soundPool.play(soundPoolMap.get(flip), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
         break;
      case (R.id.button2):
         soundPool.play(soundPoolMap.get(scratch), 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
         break;
      case (R.id.button3):
         ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this will come in handy :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't u use a switch-case statement like this?

```
public void listen(View v){
   MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
   switch(v.getid()) {
      case (R.id.sound1):
         mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.arthaswhat5);
         mediaPlayer.start();
         break;
      case (R.id.sound2):
         mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.arthaswhat6);
         mediaPlayer.start();
         break;
      case (R.id.sound3):
         ...
         ...
         ...
      case (...)
         ...
         ...
         ...
   }
}
```

Comment: I have to make this dynamic because there will be hundred of sounds in my app.
I will have to get rid of the if statement and just play the sound by doing something like :

`MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, MediaHashMap.get(buttonPressed));`