# Handle audio file on Android

Tags: android, audio, media-player, uri, android-mediaplayer

I have an audio file on drawable folder.

Suppose that the filename is: "abc.mp3".

I would use this code to reproduce the sound:

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("pathFile"));
```

What's the path of my file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be placing audio file in the `assets` folder, not in the `drawable` folder.

After placing your file in the `assets` folder you can follow this SO post : [Play audio file from assets directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289038/play-audio-file-from-the-assets-directory).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to place the audio file in the assets folder, you can place it in the "raw" folder inside the resources folder. Thus, /res/raw. Then access it like this:

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.abc);

// enable loop and play
mPlayer.setLooping(true);
mPlayer.start();
```