# Load asset files inside background service

Tags: android, android-service, android-assets

I am developing a widget that plays a random sound. My problem lies in getting the service I use to handle the `MediaPlayer` and play the sounds to load the sound files I have stored in my app's asset folder.
Instead of a `SoundPool` as in my application, I opted for a `MediaPlayer` since it has an `onCompletionListener` which allows me to stop the Service after the sound has been completely played. That way I hope to minimize the resource usage of the widget.

More precisely, in my code ([checkout the [now outdated] commit on GitHub](https://github.com/Y0hy0h/Furzknopf/tree/d72ae9a5561e4bbde2228c991f3b5515c78ad586)) I try to load a random sound with the `MediaPlayer`'s `create()` convenience method [using an `Uri` to `file:///android_asset/pathToFile`](https://github.com/Y0hy0h/Furzknopf/blob/d72ae9a5561e4bbde2228c991f3b5515c78ad586/app/src/main/java/com/y0hy0h/furzknopf/widget/VolatileFartService.java#L36).
This however throws an IOException at runtime.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent != null) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_PLAY_FART.equals(action)) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Intent received");

            String pathToFile = String.format(
                    Locale.US,
                    "fart%02d.ogg",
                    Utility.getIntBetween(1, 15)
            );
           MediaPlayer tempMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(
                    this,
                    Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/"+pathToFile)
            );
            tempMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.release();
                    stopSelf();
                }
            });
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Start playing");
            tempMediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Is there an easy way (i. e., other than a Content Provider) to **load** those asset files from **inside** the **`Service`**?

---

*[Edit, providing more information]*

Apparently it is possible to access the asset files but the `MediaPlayer` cannot load them properly.

I modified the code to this:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent != null) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_PLAY_FART.equals(action)) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Intent received");

            String pathToFile = String.format(
                    Locale.US,
                    "fart%02d.ogg",
                    Utility.getIntBetween(1, 15)
            );
            try {
                AssetFileDescriptor assetFD = this.getAssets().openFd(pathToFile);

                MediaPlayer tempMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                tempMediaPlayer.setDataSource(assetFD.getFileDescriptor());
                tempMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        stopSelf();
                    }
                });
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Start playing");
                tempMediaPlayer.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "File "+pathToFile+" could not be loaded.", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

The output I get is:

```
08-29 15:29:54.868  10191-10191/com.y0hy0h.furzknopf V/VolatileFartService﹕ Intent received
08-29 15:29:54.868  10191-10191/com.y0hy0h.furzknopf V/MediaPlayer﹕ constructor
08-29 15:29:54.868  10191-10191/com.y0hy0h.furzknopf V/MediaPlayer﹕ setListener
08-29 15:29:54.868  10191-10191/com.y0hy0h.furzknopf V/MediaPlayer﹕ setDataSource(51, 0, 576460752303423487)
08-29 15:29:54.898  10191-10191/com.y0hy0h.furzknopf E/MediaPlayer﹕ Unable to to create media player
08-29 15:29:54.908  10191-10191/com.y0hy0h.furzknopf E/VolatileFartService﹕ File fart07.ogg could not be loaded.
    java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1032)
            at com.y0hy0h.furzknopf.widget.VolatileFartService.onStartCommand(VolatileFartService.java:39)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2524)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1302)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4929)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Note that line 39 is

```
tempMediaPlayer.setDataSource(assetFD.getFileDescriptor());
```

---

Alternitavely, is there a way to *pass* the FileDescriptor or other object for the service to load?

Or might there be an even *better way* to handle the playback of possibly multiple sounds simultaneously than to put that functionality in a `Service`?

Comment: You can load file from Assets folder in the Service , but before suggesting an answer, Please include your codes so people can easily help rather than assuming what you might or might not need.

Comment: I have added a code snippet. For more of the code, I included links to my GitHub repository. Is that a bad way to provide code, should I include more code directly here at Stackoverflow?

Comment: Have you tried AssetManager asset = Context.get assets(); asset.open("filename");?

Comment: That's exactly the problem, the service has no `context` variable. Hence I can't use the `AssetManager` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to [Want2bExpert's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32286469/3287963) of moving the files into the res/raw folder, the asset files can be loaded "manually" into the MediaPlayer.

---

Apparently the assets are [not stored as would be expected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3389965/3287963). Instead, the start position and length of the asset together with its (*non* `Asset`-)`FileDescriptor` needs to be passed on to the MediaPlayer.

The working code:

```
String pathToFile = String.format(
        Locale.US,
        "fart%02d.ogg",
        Utility.getIntBetween(1, 15)
);

try {
    AssetFileDescriptor assetFD = getAssets().openFd(pathToFile);
    MediaPlayer tempMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    tempMediaPlayer.setDataSource(
            assetFD.getFileDescriptor(),
            assetFD.getStartOffset(),
            assetFD.getLength()
    );
    assetFD.close();
    tempMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
            stopSelf();
        }
    });
    tempMediaPlayer.prepare();
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Start playing");
    tempMediaPlayer.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "File "+pathToFile+" could not be loaded.", e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

- Create a raw folder inside your resource dir e.g. res/raw
- put the files to play in the raw folder
- load the file using media player as below

  MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(serviceClass.this, R.raw.sound_file_1);
  mediaPlayer.start();

Read more; 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices

Comment: From where can I get the `context` to pass on to `create()`?

Comment: Have you tried to declare a Context global variable in the service? I can't remember doing it before but give it a try. E.g. in your Service class Context context  = this;

Comment: The only place the Service gets provided a `Context` is in its static `createIntentPlayFart()` method. I cannot set a member variable there. Also, I updated my question since your proposition helped me nail down the problem further.

Comment: This is interesting, how about you have an intent,service that loads the file from Assest folder into and internal App directory, then broadcast the file directory to Receiver which then starts the Service with FileDir as an extra to intent that starts the service?

Comment: Besides Isn't Service a Context? I think the solution I gave should work.for you. See my edited answer.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Is there any reason to choose assets over raw folder? I'd like to use the asset folder, since I find the access to it a bit more convenient. And shouldn't it be possible to access the file directly instead of copying it somewhere, as I understand your first comment?

Comment: Assets is kind of raw anyway

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88264/discussion-between-j0hj0h-and-want2bexpert).