# how to play sound when two string matches in android?

Tags: android

```
EditText un = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username1);    
EditText pw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password1);    
String u = un.getText().toString();    
String p = pw.getText().toString();    
String myUser = "user1";    
String myPass = "pass1";    
public void onClickL (View view){    
  if ( (u == myUser) && (p == myPass)) /////// phone should alarm    
  else //////error    
}
```

Comment: Looks great, what's wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289038/play-audio-file-from-the-assets-directory

Comment: You can use soundpool to play some short sound

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
if ( (u == myUser) && (p == myPass))
```

to

```
if (u.equals(myUser) && p.equals(myPass))
```

Full code

```
EditText un = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username1);


EditText pw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password1);

String u = un.getText().toString();

String p = pw.getText().toString();

String myUser = "user1";

String myPass = "pass1";

public void onClickL (View view){

if (u.equals(myUser) && p.equals(myPass)){ /////// phone should alarm

else //////error

}
```