# Android MediaPlayer files path not found

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

I'm new in android development trying to play a simple audio file. I organized my audio files in multiple nested folders.

Here is the complete source on disk "app/src/main/res/raw/sounds/first/nested/my_sound_1.mp3" ... Certainly there are other files in different folders.

This is the method I'm using to play the audio file

```
fun audioPlayer(path : String, fileName: String) {

   var mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()

    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path + File.separator + fileName)
        mediaPlayer.prepare()
        mediaPlayer.start()

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

}
```

and on a button click event I'm using this code

```
audioPlayer("raw.sounds.first.nested", "my_sound_1.mp3")
```

Here is the error.

```
java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the complete source on disk "app/src/main/res/raw/sounds/first/nested/my_sound_1.mp3"

First, that would appear to be a file on your development machine, that you are trying to package into your app as a raw resource.

Second, resource directories cannot have subdirectories. You need to get rid of `sounds/first/nested/` and put your MP3 file in to `raw/`.

> This is the method I'm using to play the audio file

A resource is a file on your development machine. It is not a file on the device.

There is [a static `create()` method on `MediaPlayer` that takes a `Context` and a resource ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#create(android.content.Context,%20int)). Use that instead:

```
fun audioPlayer(context: Context, rawResourceId: Int) {
   val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer(context, rawResourceId)

   mediaPlayer.prepare()
   mediaPlayer.start()
}
```

and call it from your activity or service as `audioPlayer(this, R.raw.my_sound_1)`.

Comment: What if I want to keep the directory structure in the packaged app. Is there any way to add these folders to the packaged app?

Comment: @ToughGuy: Not as raw resources. `assets/` allows you to have an arbitrary directory structure, but [playing media from there is a bit more difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3289038/115145).