# Android Studio how to generate id for resources

Tags: android, resources, mp3

Working on a testing app, I would like to play a random mp3 soundtrack when the user clicks on a button.

So far, I am able to make the soundtrack (explicitly assigned an id) plays when the user click on the button.

```
package com.example.audio;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bell_sound)

    Button playSound = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button)

            playSound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override;
                public void onClick(View v){
                    sound.start();
        }
    })

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

However, I have no idea how to generate id to reference soundtracks in the **raw resource file** when I add more soundtrack in the future. Ideally, I can just upload more soundtrack to the **raw resource file** without touching the code, and the app can still **randomly** pick one soundtrack to play in the raw resource file when the user clicks the button.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a separate class and an Arrayadapter class which will adapt the audio when clicking on a particular image or button accordingly. Do check this link to know more https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

This to know exactly what you have to do. https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to choose randomly without touch the code, i have a solution for it follow the pseudo code

1. Create a Assets folder //Reason to have assets folder is you can perform file and folder only in assets folder. For eg, in you assets folder create a sub folder named **random_sounds** and all the random sounds you wish to play in it.
2. In your MainActivity java code get all the files name in  assets>random_sounds  folder and store it in a **String[] soundStrings**
3. And every OnClick of playSound Button, use random number generator to generate any number from 0 to length of the soundStrings containing the name. Using this generated number and using it as index value to get a random sound name from soundStrings .

---

Code to get all the file names from Assets>random_sounds

```
soundStrings = getAssets().list("random_sounds");
```

//Has to initiated in onCreate() of MainActivity

---

```
Random rand = new Random();
int rand_number_within_soundStrings_limit = rand.nextInt(soundStrings.length);
String randomSoundToPlay = soundStrings[rand_number_within_soundStrings_limit];
```

---

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289038/play-audio-file-from-the-assets-directory) on how to play audio from assets folder.

//Use above generated **randomSoundToPlay** to randomly play the audio.