# Error when trying to play mp3 in Android java app with Media Player

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to play an mp3 file which is stored in my res/raw folder properly. But it seems quite difficult to reach this aim. I have a button inside a destination defined in an navigation schema. Its name is : English. Inside its code we can find this listener attached to the only button in its view....

```
//Button related to play btn
    view.findViewById(R.id.btn_audio).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getActivity().getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.a01);
            try {
                player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
                player.prepare();
                player.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

When the button is pressed, the error is:

```
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
    at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1163)
    at com.example.myapplication.Ingles$3.onClick(Ingles.java:74)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

And I have no idea why and what to do now to solve this...Any clue?

Comment: Please refer this link (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3389965/12830957)

Answer (score 0):

### Try Closing the File Descriptor

MediaPlayer.Prepare() will throw an IOException when using an AFD only if the AFD provided cannot be read (see [MediaPlayer.setDataSource()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#setDataSource(android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor))). The developer is totally responsible for closing the file descriptor created, and not closing it can cause conflicts upon compilation. You can do that directly after MediaPlayer.setDataSource() is called.

> Sets the data source (AssetFileDescriptor) to use. It is the caller's responsibility to close the file descriptor. It is safe to do so as soon as this call returns. ([see AssetFileDescriptor.close()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetFileDescriptor#close()))

```java
    view.findViewById(R.id.btn_audio).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getActivity().getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.a01);
            try {
                player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
                afd.close();
                player.prepare();
                player.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

If the problem persists, this might mean that your file is corrupt or not the correct format. The more probable answer is that you haven't correctly retrieved your RAW file.

Comment: Humm...I've tried that and the result is: